# Can $\mathbb{P}[X>Y]$ be determined by looking at the area between the curves the curves $f_X$ and $f_Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, density-function

Say $X$ and $Y$ are 2 continuous random variables, where $f_X$ is the p.d.f of X, and $f_Y$ that of $Y$. I was wondering whether $\mathbb{P}[X>Y]$ is equivalent to the area between the curves $f_X$ and $f_Y$ in regions where the former function is greater than the latter.

I am conflicted on this, because while this does make intuitive sense on some level, I have been taught that the density function doesn't correspond to the exact probability at a certain place, but rather the 'probability per unit length'- and finding the area between the 2 curves seems to use this notion of the density function as giving the probability at $x$. So, is $\mathbb{P}[X>Y]$ the area between the curves $f_X$ and $f_Y$ in regions where the former function is greater than the latter?

Comment: You can’t conclude anything about the $\Bbb P(X>Y)$ from their densities only since the latter only provide marginal distributions, whereas the former depends on their joint distribution, that is on the *coupling* of their one dimensional distributions. There can be infinitely many very different couplings for two given one dimensional distributions. For example, if both $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal, then one coupling can be 2d standard normal which casts $\Bbb P(X>Y)=0.5$ and another coupling can put all the mass on the diagonal casting the latter probability to be $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \sim U(1,2)$.  Then $\mathbb{P}(X > Y) = 0$, but $f_X = 1_{(0,1)}$ and $f_Y = 1_{(1,2)}$, so the area between $f_X$ and $f_Y$ in regions where the former is greater than the latter is $1$.  If you don't like that the supports of $X$ and $Y$ aren't equal, you could add a $N(0,\varepsilon)$ random variable to both, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is some small constant.